# Proper way to develop an Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Well, I have recently started developing a plugin for eclipse, which is something I have never done before. After some research and test, I figured out that I can add more buttons to a toolbar (for example), by adding code into the plugin.xml, or adding extension. The thing is that I am unsure what is the PROPER way of doing all of that, because I have seen guides that say that you have to add your buttons, and other new items through the Extension manager, whilst others recommend that you add XML code straight away.

I've tried doing it with both methods, but I only succeeded by doing so in the XML. The extension menus are still confusing to me and I do not fully understand them.

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="toolbarTest.menus.sampleMenu"
               label="Sample Menu"
               mnemonic="M">
            <command
                  commandId="toolbarTest.commands.sampleCommand"
                  id="toolbarTest.menus.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="toolbarTest.commands.sampleCommand2"
                  id="toolbarTest.menus.sampleCommand2"
                  mnemonic="S">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
               id="toolbarTest.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
                  id="toolbarTest.toolbars.sampleCommand"
                  commandId="toolbarTest.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.png"
                  tooltip="Say hello world">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="toolbarTest.commands.sampleCommand2"
                  icon="icons/widgts p931sexposito.png"
                  id="toolbarTest.toolbars.sampleCommand2"
                  tooltip="Say good bye">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

The result I want to get is basically the knowledge to make eclipse plugins in a correct way. Is it by building them in the XML file? If so, is there any guide that explains the structure of them? Or the way you should build stuff, and how to do it? All the guides I have found merely explain how to create a basic plugin using a template.

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to this or really a 'proper' way. Plugins are generally a combination of extension points and classes referenced by the extension points. A longer tutorial such as [this one](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html) may help

Comment: @greg-449, thank you. Indeed, that is the guide I have been reading through... Yet I struggle to understand.

Comment: If possible, define things descriptively in `plugin.xml` instead of programmatically via Java code. The `plugin.xml` is read without starting the plug-in/bundle which makes start Eclipse faster.

Comment: Would it be possible to take a made plugin, in the form a .jar, and then try to play with it? As in, load the plugin on my eclipse, by only having the jar file so that I can begin to play with... I tried to load it before but it didn't do it quite properly. Perhaps It can't be done.

Comment: [Section 3](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#runtimeeclipse_starting) in that tutorial tells you how to run a test instance of Eclipse containing your plug-in. This is a much safer way to play with a plug-in than trying to install it in your main Eclipse

Comment: Oh, I am already testing my plugins by launching an Eclipse on my server, and playing around with them. What I meant is that If I could take a plugin that exists, from someone else (A .jar file), and load it as to edit it myself, which is what I will have to do in the end. @greg-449

Comment: A plug-in jar doesn't contain any source code so it is difficult to change.

Comment: I figured out that the options that were missing on the Eclipse were due to PDE libraries and other eclipse extensions missing.
Although, I have given up on the project. We had to modify an .jar from our company from which we don't have the source code anymore.  Once we loaded it, after a couple days of trying to understand how it works we kind of gave up. It seems like a .jar inception! There's a jar inside the plugin that contains all its logic, If we load it, the exact same plugin appears. It's an endless cycle.
Anyways, thanks for your help.